# Prefering in place rotation

Tags: navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to have the robot prefer in place rotation to more circuitous changes in direction?  The scenario I have is that the robot moves to the end of a one meter wide corridor, then I set a new goal within Rviz for it to return to its original location.  Often the robot tries to do a circular turn, but hits a wall before it can make it.  The most efficient path would simply be to do a 180 degree turn on the spot, then start driving.

This might have something to do with the minimum ranging capability of the Kinect sensor, such that it might not see the nearby wall as an obstacle.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11901/prefering-in-place-rotation/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe if you increase the inflation of the obstacles the robot will enter a escape maneuver and then rotate in place. Although this may result in undesired behaviors in normal navigation mode.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0